# Cannot find installed plugin on my Eclipse IDE after update

Tags: eclipse

I have updated my ubuntu desktop and the eclipse which i was running on the system got updated automatically. After the update all the options inside the eclipse are the same as they used to be by default.. all my customization has been lost and the perspectives, project templates are no more. Now when i tried to installed the plugins, eclipse returns me that the selected plugins has already been installed..

I want to know is it common with eclipse to show this behavior after each update? How to can i get back my old customization without deleting the installed plugin folder and install them from scratch again..

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Which plugin?

Comment: oops!! sorry to mention it! Version: 3.5.2 and the not a single plugin.. all plugins are not recognised. I have installed pydev, aptana, xml support, ajax, js support. nothing seems to be working.. i am sure they have been detected as IDE is not allowing me to install it again.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't met the issue you mentioned before. but I suggest you can check whether your workspace location is changed after your plugin is installed/updated.

Actually, all your eclipse plugins configuration/preferences settings are stored into your {workspace_home}.metadata folder. it's not relevant about what plugin eclipse has installed, That's the reason why each time switch workspace, you need to re-customized preferences settings.

So, if you want to protect customized settings, pls consider backup .metadata folder properly.